# Django - Change time format for a locale

Tags: django, localization, django-templates

I'm working on a project which uses l10n.
If I set the locale to EN and try to display a time (08:00), I get:

```
8 a.m.
```

If I set the locale to FR I get:

```
08:00:00
```

But it should be something like:

```
8h
```

Why am I getting this format ? How can I get the proper format ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently there is no default time format set for FR locale.

What you can do is configure the [format module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-FORMAT_MODULE_PATH):

```
# myproject/settings.py
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = 'myproject.formats'
```

Create it:

```
myproject/
    formats/
        __init__.py
        fr/
            __init__.py
            formats.py
```

And define the french format:

```
# myproject/formats/fr/formats.py
TIME_FORMAT = 'G:i'
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can change the format if you are using localization, from my understanding of this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/.

Is `USE_L10N = True`? If so, it will override `settings.TIME_FORMAT` and `settings.TIME_INPUT_FORMATS` values: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#time-format

You can write your own "localization" context processor or template filter, based on the selected language.

Comment: I confirm that `TIME_FORMAT` overrides the default value from `USE_L10N` when set through format module